# Get Resource URL Path in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, firebase, path

Trying to get the path of a JSON file I have in my resource folder but failing to do so with `getResource().getPath()`.  I would like to get this URL in as robust a manner as possible.

```
public static void initializeFirebase() {
        try {
            URL url = getResource("google-services.json");
            System.out.println(url.getPath());
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions
                    .Builder()
                    .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(url.getPath()))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/")
                    .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The above function prints:
`/Users/username/Documents/Spring_Project/springbackend/build/resources/main/google-services.json` before throwing the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read service account
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.setServiceAccount(FirebaseOptions.java:82)
    at live.cibc.labs.springbackend.SpringbackendApplication.initializeFirebase(SpringbackendApplication.java:188)
    at live.cibc.labs.springbackend.SpringbackendApplication.main(SpringbackendApplication.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["project_id"] not found.
```

Obviously it cannot find my project_id, as my google-services.json is under `src/main/resources/google-services.json`.

How should I fetch the path is as robust a manner as possible?

#### google-services.json

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "XXXXXXXX",
    "firebase_url": "https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "XXXX-XXX",
    "storage_bucket": "XXXXXXXX.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:XXXXXXXXX:android:XXXXXXX",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "my.spring.project"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "XXXXX-XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "XXXXXX"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Comment: Your `google-services.json` is simply in the root of your classpath. When your application is running there is no `src/main/resources` anymore. You are using Spring, then use that. Just use `Resource res = new ClassPathResource("google-services.json")` to get it. Then do `res.getInputStream()` when needed. Don't try to do those things yourself. You can also `@Autowire` the `ResourceLoader` and do `Resource res=resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/google-services-json");` and proceed as mentioned earlier.

Comment: `resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/google-services-j‌​son");` and `resourceLoader.getResource("google-services-j‌​son");` both return null

Comment: Well of course... Instead of copy-pasting, you might want to check that code (we also make errors)... That obviously isn't the name of your file...

Comment: If you're referring to the `google-services-json` I did amend your mistake, but to no avail. `getResource("google-services.j‌​son")` is null and `getResource("classpath:/google-services.j​so‌​n");` throws a JSON failed to read exception

Comment: Then it does exist and your JSOn isn't what your API isn't expecting. If the file doesn't exist it would be `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ended up being something really stupid on my part!  In the firebase console there are 2 JSON files you can download.

- `google-services.json` is for the client
- `service-account-credentials.json` is for the server admin SDK (the one I should have been using)

Don't mix the two up!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that you use Spring, the best way to do so is to use Springs [ClassPathResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html):

```java
public static void initializeFirebase() {    
  try {
      Resource googleServicesResource = new ClassPathResource("google-services.json");
      FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions
              .Builder()
              .setServiceAccount(googleServicesResource.getInputStream())
              .setDatabaseUrl("https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/")
              .build();
      FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read service account` and `Caused by: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["project_id"] not found.` because it cannot find the file

Comment: can you provide the json? It could be that it is malformed. json keys have be quoted.

Comment: Posted, although that is unlikely, considering it was downloaded directly from my firebase console without modification.